# Procedural Maze Algorithm With Cells Determined Independently of Neighbors

Tags: algorithm, infinite, maze, chunks

I was thinking about maze algorithms recently (mostly because I'm working on a game, but I felt this is a more general question than game development related). In simple terms, I was wondering if there is a sort of maze algorithm that can generate (a possibly infinite number of) cells without any information specifically about the cell's neighbors. I imagine, if such a thing were possible, it would rely heavily upon noise functions such as Perlin or Simplex.

Each cell has four walls, these are used when actually rendering the maze so that corridors and walls are not the same thickness.

Let's say, for example, I'd like a cell at (32, 15) to generate its walls.

I know of algorithms like Ellers (which requires a limited number of columns, but infinite rows) and the Virtual fractal Mazes algorithm (which needs to know previous cells in order to build upon them infinitely in both x and y directions).

Does anyone know of any algorithm I could look into for this specific request? If not, are there any algorithms that are good for chunk-based mazes that you know of?

(Note: I did search around for a bit through StackOverflow to see if there were any questions with similar requests to mine, but I did not come across any. If you happen to know of one, a link would be greatly appreciated :D)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aldous-Broder algorithm: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/17/maze-generation-aldous-broder-algorithm

Comment: @yacc That's one I've looked at before, it's pretty inefficient and I don't think it's too tile-able. I've been thinking, and I figure that I can just generate mazes when necessary, and create paths between them. It would look really strange from above, but might work when actually in the maze. Thank you for replying, though.

Comment: Welcome. You could optimize that algo by keeping a list of non-visited tiles and removing one tile randomly from it. And you could enhance it further to work with rooms/cells of random size.

Comment: @yacc That could work, I'll have to see how that does

Comment: Some really good random 2D maze results were given by Blizzard in Diablo. However, if you take a closer look, the algorithm behind it seemed trivial, and I think it was derived from Aldous-Broder.

Answer (score 2):

Seeeeeecreeeets. My preeeeciooouss secretts. But yeah I can understand the frustration so I'll throw this one to you OP/SO. Feel free to update the PCG Wiki if you're not as lazy as me :3

There are actually *many* ways to do this. Some of the best techniques for procgen are:

- Asking what you **really** want.
- Design backwards. Play in reverse. Result is forwards.
- Look at a random sampling of your target goal and try to see overall patterns.

But to get back to the question, there are two *simple* ways and they both start from asking what your really want. I'll give those first.

The first is to create 2 layers. Both are random noise. You connect the top and the bottom so they're fully connected. No isolated portions. This is asking what you really want which is connected-ness. And then guaranteeing it in a local clean-up step. (tbh I forget the function applied to layer 2 that guarantees connected-ness. I can't find the code atm.... But I remember it was a really simple local function... XOR, Curl, or something similar. Maybe you can figure it out before I fix this).

The second way is using the properties of your functions. As long as your random function is *smooth enough* you can take the gradient and assign a tile to it. The way you assign the tiles changes the maze structure but you can guarantee connectivity by clever selection of tiles for each gradient (b/c similar or opposite gradients are more likely to be near each other on a smooth gradient function). From here your smooth random can be any form of Perlin Noise, etc. Once again a asking what you want technique.

For backwards-reversed you unfortunately have an NP problem (I'm not sure if it's hard, complete, or whatever it's been a while since I've worked on this...). So while you *could* generate a random map of distances down a maze path. And then from there generate the actual obstacles... it's not really advisable. There's also a ton of consideration on different cases even for small mazes...

```
 012
 123
 234
```

Is simple. There's a column in the lower right corner of 0 and the middle 2 has an _| shaped wall.

```
042
123
234
```

This one makes less sense. You still are required to have the same basic walls as before on all the non-changed squares... But you can't have that 4. It needs to be within 1 of at least a single neighbor. (I mean you could have a +3 cost for that square by having something like a conveyor belt or something, but then we're out of the maze problem) Okay so....

```
032
123
234
```

Makes more sense but the 2 in the corner is nonsense once again. Flipping that from a trough to a peak would give.

```
034
123
234
```

Which makes sense. At any rate. If you can get to this point then looking at local neighbors will give you walls if it's +/-1 then no wall. Otherwise wall. Also note that you can break the rules for the distance map in a consistent way and make a maze just fine. (Like instead of allowing a column picking a wall and throwing it up. This is just loop splitting at this point and should be safe)

For random sampling as the final one that I'm going to look at... Certain maze generation algorithms in the limit take on some interesting properties either as an average configuration or after millions of steps. Some form Voronoi regions. Some form concentric circles with a randomly flipped wall to allow a connection between loops. Etc. The loop one is good example to work off of. Create a set of loops. Flip a random wall on each loop. One will delete a wall which will create access to the next loop. One will split a path and offer a dead-end and a continuation. For a random flip to be a failure there has to be an opening and a split made right next to each other (unless you allow diagonals then we're good). So make loops. Generate random noise per loop. Xor together. Replace local failures with a fixed path if no diagonals are allowed.

So how do we get random noise per loop? Or how do we get better loops than just squares? Just take a random function. Separate divergence and now you have a loop map. If you have the differential equations for the source random function you can pick one random per loop. A simpler way might be to generate concentric circular walls and pick a random point at each radius to flip. Then distort the final result. You have to be careful your distortion doesn't violate any of your path-connected-ness conditions at that point though.